# Swift failed to produce diagnostic for expression

Tags: swift

I am trying to use a switch statement on an enum within a View, and it confuses the compiler:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct LexicalItemView : View {
    let lexicalItem: LexicalItem
    var body: some View {
        switch self.lexicalItem {
        case .noun(let nounModel):
            Text(nounModel.gender)
        case .verb(let verbModel):
            Text(verbModel.aspect)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my enum:

```
enum LexicalItemEnum {
    case noun(Noun)
    case verb(Verb)
}
```

How can I unconfuse the swift compiler or otherwise get this to compile?

Comment: `switch` works only in SwiftUI 2.0 (iOS14)